# Form tag inside master page and content page

Tags: asp.net

I have one master page and several content pages , I need to put a form tag inside a master page to handle sending data from my html elements and do this for my content pages as well .but I need to understand what is the best way to structure for such this scenario and what would be the effect of form tag of master page on content pages ? is it possible to put form tag in content pages when the master page has this tag inside itself ? I appreciate if I have in detail explanation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<form runat="server">` element lives in the master page by default when you add a new one to your project; all child pages are implemented using ContentPlaceHolders.

For example, the master page: -

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

You can have as many ContentPlaceHolders as you need (often only one is needed though). If you then add a "child page using master page", the page-specific content is added inside the relevant `<asp:Content>` element - these are added by default once you have specified the master page to use when adding a "child page using master page": -

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <!-- your markup, controls etc.. -->

</asp:Content>
```

Have a read of the MSDN docs for more - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response ,but my main question is ,later when you add content page is it possible to have a form tag inside content page or the form tag inside master page can handle the html elements inside content pages ?

Comment: You can add a form tag inside the content page, but it cannot be marked runat="server" - there can only be one of these per page (including master + child). There should usually be no need to do this; the content in your child pages *will* be inside a <form> tag, the one defined in the master page

Comment: If you're using <form> tags for structure or some CSS rule, just use a DIV instead to wrap the content in the child page.

Comment: Thanks again ,I have another question ,if later in code-behind I want to use Request.Form[] to get the html element's data inside the content page what would happen ? is it possible to do this in content page or it would happen in master page ,I mean which *.cs file is responsible for getting the data ?

Comment: You would still be able to access content via Request.Form - which you would be able to access in the child page - but why would you ? If you've added asp.net controls to your child page, your child page could just access them directly ? Can you post an example of the child page markup ?

Comment: for ezample this html control <input type='text' name='address' id='address'/> I want to get the value in code-behind ,as as I asked is it possible to get it with request.form in content page or it should happen in master page ?

Comment: You can access that from the child page via Request.Form; if you add a runat="server" tag to it you will have a valid HtmlTextInput control you can access from the child page instead of having to use Request.Form